# My code returns a list full of zeros when it should have values

Tags: python, function, loops, tuples, data-analysis

As the question states, I've written a piece of code to find the average of some data over a number of rows from a large data set. For some reason the code now just returns a list of tuples with zeros in them, it used to show values when testing on smaller bits of data but after refining the code it now doesnt work. I cant seem to see where I've broken something, thank you for any help.

I've pasted the whole function below, i cant seem to see the error. My guess is its something to do with the loop but i dont understand where there is a problem.

```
def makeAverageList(input,col1=1,col2=2,monthavg=200):
    f = open(input + ".txt", "r")
    col1avg = []
    col2avg = []
    points = []
    length = len(f.readlines())
    count = 1
    maxcount = float(length/monthavg)
    while True:
        lines = list(islice(f, monthavg))
        col1list = []
        col2list = []
        linelist = []
        for i in lines:
            linelist.append(i[1:-2])
        for l in linelist:
            line = []
            line = l.split(",")
            col1list.append(float(line[col1]))
            col2list.append(float(line[col2]))
        A = float(sum(col1list))
        col1avg.append(float(A/monthavg))
        B = float(sum(col2list))
        col2avg.append(float(B/monthavg))
        count = count + 1
        if not count < maxcount:
            break
    for z in range(len(col1avg)):
        P = (float(col1avg[z]), float(col2avg[z]))
        points.append(P)
    return points

print(makeAverageList("data.monthly_nh_clean"))

[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)]
```

The data set is many lines of values like this:

,1850.08,-0.844,-0.921,-0.747,-1.036,-0.652,-1.374,-0.314,-1.051,-0.635,-1.413,-0.274

,1850.17,-0.053,-0.119,0.032,-0.254,0.148,-0.621,0.515,-0.270,0.166,-0.661,0.556

,1850.25,-0.699,-0.794,-0.632,-0.891,-0.508,-1.124,-0.274,-0.910,-0.495,-1.174,-0.229

In the code i format it, split it, and take values from it. i dont understand why its stopped working.

Comment: Python 2.7 or 3? You calculate for example `maxcount = float(length/monthavg)`. If you are in Python 2.7 and `length` as well as `monthavg` are integers, their fraction will be an integer again! Taking the float afterwards wouldn't help in this case. Might this be an issue?

Comment: Otherwise, can you please provide some exemplary input data?

Comment: It must be python3 because of the `print().`

Comment: Welcome Hamza! Have you stepped in with a debugger? What have you learned?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, im running python 3.7. And Michele i honestly dont know how to use the debugger.

Comment: It seems as though the islice function is not taking any data.

Comment: Is it on purpose, that you strip away the last digit of the last number in each line?

Comment: @Hamza This sounds like a great time to learn then, right? I recommend reading this article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Use context managers to handle files. That data is valid CSV, no? Why not use a CSV library?

Comment: Yes Daniel, it strips the \n that you get from the new line. Thanks Alexander, ill check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only iterate once over a opened file. The first time, you consume all the input is to determine the number of lines. The second time, you try to read the lines inside the while loop, the file is already consumed, and gives no results, and therefore a empty list `linelist`.

To simplify all, you don't need `maxcount`, but check for empty `col1list`:

```
def makeAverageList(input, col1=1, col2=2, monthavg=200):
    points = []
    with open(input + ".txt") as lines:
        while True:
            col1list = []
            col2list = []
            for line in islice(lines, monthavg):
                line = line.strip(',').split(",")
                col1list.append(float(line[col1]))
                col2list.append(float(line[col2]))
            if not col1list:
                # end of file
                break
            avg1 = sum(col1list) / len(col1list)
            avg2 = sum(col2list) / len(col2list)
            points.append((avg1, avg2))
    return points
```

Comment: Ah i had no idea you could only iterate over the file once, thanks for the help!